# Can't add new value to empty dataframe

Tags: pandas

Hi I created an empty dataframe, when I added new value to the dataframe, the new column is created, but the new value is not added, so  the dataframe is still empty.

```
unrealized_amt_df=pd.DataFrame()
unrealized_amt_df['Name']='abc'
```

The shape of the dataframe becomes (0,1).
When I run the following:

```
unrealized_amt_df['Date']=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

The shape becomes (0,2) now.The columns are 'Name','Date'

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think better is create list and then Dataframe:

```
L = ['abc', datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
unrealized_amt_df=pd.DataFrame([L], columns=['Name','Date'])

print (unrealized_amt_df)
  Name        Date
0  abc  2020-04-29
```

But is it possible with specified new index value, here `0` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), but slow, so [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316):

```
unrealized_amt_df=pd.DataFrame()
unrealized_amt_df.loc[0, 'Name']='abc'
unrealized_amt_df.loc[0, 'Date']=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (unrealized_amt_df)
  Name        Date
0  abc  2020-04-29
```